# How do I quickly move a file from one tab to the other in PCManFM

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

If I use F3 in Nautilus, I right-click on the file and select "move to other pane". How do I move a file from one tab to the other in PCManFM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### To move a file between folders open in two adjacent tabs:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and without releasing it, press one after the other: <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> (then release Ctrl).

- This is just Ctrl+X to cut, Ctrl+Tab to switch tabs and Ctrl+V to paste, thus accomplishing a move to the next tab.

#### Do the same using a single shortcut (but still two or three key presses)

1. *xdotool* allows automation of keyboard and mouse clicks/movements; install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
2. Copy and paste the below to an `sh` file, say `pcmanmove.sh` in your home directory:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+x
   sleep 0.125
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers Ctrl+Tab
   sleep 0.125
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v
   ```

   Make it executable with `chmod +x ~/pcmanmove.sh`
3. Open Settings...Keyboard, and go to the Shortcuts tab. Create a custom shortcut, naming it whatever you want, and setting the "Command" path to `/home/username/pcmanmove.sh`. Click Apply. The right-column will say "Disable", click on it and you'll see "New Accelerator": press your shortcut key combo. I chose `Ctrl+Alt+X`, for example.

   [image]
4. Now, with two tabs open in PCmanFM, press the custom shortcut to accomplish the move in one-quarter of a second! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a common bug on PCManFM or something, which is commented [over here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3403965&group_id=156956&atid=801864).

You can switch Tabs using [Alt] and a number from the alpha-numeric keyboard, starting with 1 for the first tab, 2 for the second one and so on.

Nevertheless, it might not work when BloqNum is turned on in your numeric keyboard, which seems to be fixed by a patch provided in the mentioned site. I tried to apply the patch but it seems to be a patch that should be applied to the PCManFM source code, so I can't inform if this is going to work.

Good luck!

Comment: Not sure you got me right. I want to permanently move a file from one tab to the other as opposed to just copying it via drag and drop.

Comment: Oh sorry! You're right. My fault. Anyway, if you don't mind I would left this answer over here just in case that anyone else find it useful. Sorry again.